# How can I map data point in XY axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, coordinates

I have a single data points as below.

First data point = 0.3,
Second data point = 0.2,
Third data point = 0.5,
Forth data point = 0.6

I want to map these points in XY coordinates as Cartesian coordinates. Then, later add other points.

How should I do that using EXCEL?

Comment: Which ones are Xs and which are Ys?

Comment: I want to create X axis and Y axis from these data column values

Comment: So are the points (0.3, 0.2) and (0.5, 0.6)?  (i.e. first point has an x value of 0.3 and a y value of 0.2, and the second point has a x value of 0.5 and a y value of 0.6)

Comment: @A.M. No. These data points are one column. I want to create X coordinate and Y coordinate from these values.

Comment: I still don't understand.  What is the first point?  (What is its x value, and what is its y value?)

Comment: I modify the text. There are four data points and I want to map it.

Comment: Yes but you don't have any dimensions you could map them in. Right now they're just scalar values. That would merely give you one axis not two. If say you would arrive at a value of 0.3 XY by computing 0.15 X*2 Y you would have something you could use as your axis (X and Y) but if you only have a flat value you could merely have one axis which is probably going to be the column title.

Comment: You have numbers and you've listed them in a sequence.  Is there something that requires them to be in that sequence or could the values be in another order?  If what you're showing is the order of numbers you draw from a hat, that's not XY data.  You can use a line graph to plot them in sequence.  If they are the results of some process, or represent results at points in time, and that scale is important, the values or times that produced these numbers would be the X values, and these would be the Y values.  A scatter chart (XY chart), would show the relationship between X and Y.

Comment: Are you using decimals (instead of commas) as separators?  Is the first point (0,3), meaning an x-value of 0 and a y value of 3?  Otherwise I don't see how you have x-value-y-value pairs, which are needed to do an XY plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly just have one set of values, then a **bar chart** would be more appropriate than an X-Y chart.

If you absolutely want to have an XY chart, though, you could

1. put a column of 0, 1, 2, 3 (etc.) to the left of the data you mentioned,
2. highlight both sets of numbers, and then
3. create an XY chart.

...and just add to those columns in the future if needed (counting on the left, new data on the right) and right-click on the chart to point to the larger data series.